# How to separate this array?

Tags: java

How do I solve the following problem?

[Please see link here](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/sums-in-loop).

My code only works when the data is entered horizontally.
How would I go about changing my code in order to be able to display the sums like my 2nd example above in the link?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sums_in_loop {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String code = scanner.nextLine();
    String list[] = code.split(" ");
    for( int counter = 0; counter < list.length; counter++) {
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println(sum + " ");

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`. The latter prints a new line after what ever you ask it to print, the former does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the URL you provided, the solution is rather straight-forward.

1. Ask the user how many pairs to enter
2. Declare an array of integers with a size of the user input from step 1
3. Run a loop based on the user input from step 1

   1. Declare an array of integers with a size of 2
   2. Run a nested loop of two to get user input for the two integers
   3. Add the two numbers into the array from step 2
4. Display results

With that in mind (I assume only valid data is being used):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many pairs do you want to enter? ");
    int numberOfPairs = input.nextInt();
    int[] sums = new int[numberOfPairs];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPairs; i++) {
        int[] numbers = new int[2];
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            // Be sure to enter two numbers with a space in between
            numbers[j] = input.nextInt();
        }
        sums[i] = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
    }

    System.out.println("Answers:");
    for (int sum : sums) {
        System.out.print(sum + " ");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
How many pairs do you want to enter? 3
100 8
15 245
1945 54
Answers:
108 260 1999
```